# Table value function not returning results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function

My table value function will returns empty results. I am not sure if I've got my table value function formatted correctly.

I've hard coded all of the variables and run each select statement by  their selves but I cannot get the table to return an results.

I also filled a table variable and did a select @Table_Var and this did return the correct results, so it has something to do with the way i've got my code structured.

All of the statement are working correctly, I am having trouble returning from the function with the data.

Anyone see anything right off hand that i've got wrong?

### EDIT

I've move that loose code to a function so that it is not so confusing.

The function works correctly and everything else, accept for when i try to return the table.

```
--select * from  [dbo].[fn_Professionals_GetMiniUserInfo](null,'a9cec535-ac48-4197-b8a0-87702cb14e52') 
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_NonPros_GetMiniUserInfo] 
(
 @NonProID  INT = NULL,
 @UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL
) 
RETURNS 
    @Table_Var TABLE 
(
    -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
    Avatar     NVARCHAR(50), 
    ID         int,
    FName      varchar(50),
    LName      varchar(50),
    Title      varchar(20),
    UserID     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    CompanyID  INT,
    CoWorkers  INT,
    Street     varchar(60),
    City       varchar(30),
    StateCD    char(2),
    ZipCode    varchar(5),
    WorksFor   VARCHAR(30),
    Phone      VARCHAR(12),
    Email      NVARCHAR(256)
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @Table_Var

SELECT
    (SELECT [AFCCInc_Com].[dbo].[aspnet_fn_GetProfileElement]('Avatar',ap.PropertyNames,ap.PropertyValuesString )FROM AFCCInc_Com.dbo.aspnet_Profile ap
                                                                                                                 WHERE ap.UserId = nonPro.UserID)as'Avatar',
            na.NonProID'ID',c.FirstName'FName',c.LastName'LName',c.Title,@UserID 'UserID',
            ci.CompanyID,ci.CoWorkers,a.AddressLine, cit.City,s.StateCD,z.ZIPCode,ci.CompanyName'WorksFor',
            p.Phone,
                  (SELECT Email FROM AFCCInc_Com.dbo.aspnet_Membership m WHERE m.UserId = nonPro.UserID)'Email'

                  FROM  NonPros.NonPros nonPro         with(nolock)                                   JOIN
                  NonPros.utbNonProsUtbAddresses    na with(nolock) on na.NonProID = nonPro.NonProID  JOIN
                  dbo.fn_GetCompanyInfo(@UserID)    ci              ON ci.UserID   = nonPro.UserID    JOIN
                  Person.utbAddresses                a with(nolock) ON a.AddressID = na.AddressID     JOIN
                  [Person].[UtbAddressesutbContact] ac with(nolock)on ac.AddressID = a.AddressID      JOIN
                  Person.utbContact                  c with(nolock)ON ac.ContactID = c.ContactID      JOIN
                  Person.utbContactUtbPhones        cp with(nolock)ON c.ContactID = cp.ContactID      JOIN
                  Person.utbPhones                   p with(nolock)ON p.PhoneID = cp.PhonesID         JOIN
                  Person.utbZipCodes                 z WITH(NOLOCK) ON z.ZipCodeID = a.ZipCodeID      JOIN
                  Person.utbCitys                  cit WITH(NOLOCK) ON cit.CityID  = z.CityID         JOIN
                  Person.utbStates                   s WITH(NOLOCK) ON s.StateCD = z.StateCD

                  WHERE c.ContactTypeID = 7/*me*/ 
                  AND p.PhoneTypeID = 6/*main*/
                  AND nonPro.UserID = 'a9cec535-ac48-4197-b8a0-87702cb14e52';
    RETURN 
    END;


    alter FUNCTION fn_GetCompanyInfo (@UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
RETURNS 
@Table_Var TABLE 
(
    UserID      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    CompanyID   INT, 
    CompanyName VARCHAR(50),
    CoWorkers   INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @Table_Var

          SELECT @UserID,
                 p.ProfessionalID, 
                 p.ProfessionalName,
                (SELECT COUNT(NonProID)'CoWorkers' FROM BuildingPros.utbProfessionalsUtbNonPros with(nolock)WHERE ProfessionalID = p.ProfessionalID)

                                    FROM BuildingPros.utbProfessionalsUtbNonPros bp with(nolock)                                       JOIN
                                         BuildingPros.utbProfessionals            p with(nolock)ON p.ProfessionalID = bp.ProfessionalID

                      WHERE bp.NonProID = (SELECT NonProID FROM NonPros.NonPros where UserID = @UserID);
    RETURN 
END
```

GO

Comment: Can you please tell where are you using your parameters?   `@NonProID  INT = NULL,  @UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL`

Comment: Try pulling the contents of the function out into a query window.  Declare a table variable to match the function definition, and declare variables to match the functions input.  Then set the variables to the input values you are using.  See if that works.  If it does the problem is in your function definition.  If not it's in your query.  With the code in a query window (not a function) it will be MUCH easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

After I cleaned the code up and move those selects above the insert into my table variable everything worked.

I believe this segment was my issue.

```
**(SELECT [AFCCInc_Com].[dbo].[aspnet_fn_GetProfileElement]('Avatar',ap.PropertyNames,ap.PropertyValuesString)),**
```

.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT [AFCCInc_Com].[dbo].[aspnet_fn_GetProfileElement]('Avatar',ap.PropertyNames,ap.PropertyValuesString)),
            na.NonProID'ID',c.FirstName'FName',c.LastName'LName',c.Title,'a9cec535-ac48-4197-b8a0-87702cb14e52' 'UserID',
            ci.CompanyID,ci.CoWorkers,a.AddressLine, cit.City,s.StateCD,z.ZIPCode,ci.CompanyName'WorksFor',
            p.Phone,
                  (SELECT Email FROM AFCCInc_Com.dbo.aspnet_Membership m WHERE m.UserId = nonPro.UserID)'Email'

                  FROM  
                  NonPros.NonPros nonPro                                                  JOIN
                  AFCCInc_Com.dbo.aspnet_Profile ap      ON ap.UserId =nonPro.UserID       JOIN
                  NonPros.utbNonProsUtbAddresses    na   ON na.NonProID = nonPro.NonProID  JOIN
                  dbo.fn_GetCompanyInfo('a9cec535-ac48-4197-b8a0-87702cb14e52')    ci   ON ci.UserID   = nonPro.UserID    JOIN
                  Person.utbAddresses                a   ON a.AddressID = na.AddressID     JOIN
                  [Person].[UtbAddressesutbContact] ac   ON ac.AddressID = a.AddressID     JOIN
                  Person.utbContact                  c   ON ac.ContactID = c.ContactID     JOIN
                  Person.utbContactUtbPhones        cp   ON c.ContactID = cp.ContactID    JOIN
                  Person.utbPhones                   p   ON p.PhoneID = cp.PhonesID       JOIN
                  Person.utbZipCodes                 z   ON z.ZipCodeID = a.ZipCodeID      JOIN
                  Person.utbCitys                  cit   ON cit.CityID  = z.CityID         JOIN
                  Person.utbStates                   s   ON s.StateCD = z.StateCD

                  WHERE c.ContactTypeID = 7/*me*/ 
                  AND p.PhoneTypeID = 6/*main*/
                  AND nonPro.UserID = 'a9cec535-ac48-4197-b8a0-87702cb14e52'
    RETURN
```